# Pass function with nested function and current value with array.map

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to use array.map but I am having an issue passing the current value of the array that is being passed through the function.

My array is an array of objects.

I want to run my `toNodes` function on each object.

`toNodes` takes an argument of a HTML string, which is returned from another function called `singleTemplate`

`singleTemplate` also takes an argument which should be the **current** object.

So at the moment I am running the following but I am not passing the needed object into the `singleTemplate` function, so it's undefined.

`array.map(toNodes(singleTemplate(obj)))`

`obj` doesn't exist though... what do I put in the parameters for `singleTemplate` to pass the current object from the map?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) expects a function, and you are passing it the results of your functions.

Instead, use an anonymous function (or an arrow function):

```
array.map(function(obj) {
  return toNodes(singleTemplate(obj));
})
```

Comment: Thanks! This makes sense and helps me understand what I was doing wrong IRT passing the result rather than the function :)

Answer (score 1):

One line to solve issue:

```
array.map(obj => toNodes(singleTemplate(obj)))
```